# Код в списке делает нумерацию в порядке возрастания. Но это занимает 3 строчки и +1 переменную, можно ли его укоротить?

Tags: python, list, инспекция-кода, for

```
a = [12,41,31,4124,124]
b = a[:]
b.sort()
for i in b:
    print(a.index(i) + 1)
```

Comment: Если честно, не вижу особой проблемы в том, что код занимает 3 строчки - так он более читаем. Я вижу проблему в использовании index - это линейный поиск, что делает сложность алгоритма квадратичной, и на больших списках это будет тормозить. Плюс, если в списке будут одинаковые элементы, то index будет всегда находить только первый из них. Если что-то оптимизировать, то лучше оптимизировать алгоритм, чем количество строк.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Вариант 1: "vanilla Python"

```
res = [i for i,x in sorted(enumerate(a, 1), key=lambda x: x[1])]
print(*res, sep="\n")
```

#### Вариант 2: используем Numpy

```
import numpy as np

res = np.argsort(a) + 1
print(*res, sep="\n")
```

Вывод:

```
1
3
2
5
4
```